# IntelliJ disappearing error

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm working on a project in `IntelliJ Community edition 2016.2.4`

I've noticed that sometimes a module in my project will show an error in a Java class, but as soon as I open the class the error disappears, but randomly reappears again until I click into it again, has anybody else encountered this?

I'm not 100% sure this is a bug with IntelliJ and feel like it might be caused by conflicting libraries or something along those lines.

Comment: Could be that you have a dependency to some other module and that module is being rebuilt or something similair. Never had that myself though. 

Have you looked at the module settings for the problematic module to see if you don't have errors in your dependencies?

Comment: Randomly?  No. I sincerely doubt it's a bug in IntelliJ.  You can check the bug list to see, but I'd be surprised.